# Gtk3+ keyboard shortcuts without signal matching

Tags: application-development, python, gtk3

I am in the process of creating my first Gtk3+ application using python, and I am quite frustrated with the lack of documentation :(

Well, what I'm trying to do is to configure the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button to remove an item from my `TreeView`, and I don't have a remove button in order to bind the "clicked" signal of it for my code.

This is my code:

```
def make_shortcuts(self):
        self.my_accelerators = Gtk.AccelGroup()
        self.add_accel_group(self.my_accelerators)
        self.add_accelerator(self.treeview, "<Delete>", signal="???")

def add_accelerator(self, widget, accelerator, signal="activate"):
        if accelerator is not None:
            key, mod = Gtk.accelerator_parse(accelerator)
            widget.add_accelerator(signal, self.my_accelerators, key, mod, Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE)
```

I don't get how a keyboard shortcut must be binded to a signal and not to a function. Binding to a function is way more flexible.

Is there any way I can bind a keyboard shortcut to a function?

Comment: What do you mean by not having a remove button?

Comment: If I did have a remove button for my list, I could easily bind the Delete button to the "clicked" signal of my button, which is binded to the delete function and problem solved. So, I don't have and I don't want to have such a button. I just want when I press the Delete button the function that would run IF I had a remove button to run.

Comment: What does your delete function look like?

Comment: @Anonimista This is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using accelerators, you can connect the [key-press-event](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-key-press-event) signal of your `TreeView` to a function and check if it was the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key that was pressed.

```
def on_treeview_key_press_event(self, widget, event):
    key = Gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval)
    if key == 'Delete':
        self.remove_items()
```